# Policy based routing

Tags: linux, iptables, routing, load-balancing

I found very good article on load balancing at http://www.diegolima.org/wordpress/?p=36..
I could not implement it though as my requirement is slightly different from pure load balancing.

We have two ISP connections. I have connected both these routers to Linux server on eth0 (public ip 121.XXX.XX.XXX) and eth1(192.168.129.XXX) respectively, and our internal network is on eth2 (192.168.1.XXX).

I have decided that that our FTP should use eth1 interface, Squid should use eth0, Sendmail should use eth0 and some users should use eth0 and some other user should use eth1.

Can anybody tell if it is possible, how can I achieve this using iptables and iproute2?
Step by step help is highly appreciated.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

Configure IPROUTE2

```
echo "4        sendmail" >> /etc/iproute2/rt_tables
ip route add 121.XXX.XX.XXX/MASK dev eth0 src 121.XXX.XX.XXX table sendmail
ip route add 192.168.1.XXX/24 dev eth2 table sendmail
ip route add default via GATEWAY1 table sendmail
ip ru add from 121.XXX.XX.XXX lookup sendmail
ip ru add fwmark 2 table sendmail
ip route flush cache
```

Configure IPTABLES

```
iptables -t mangle -I OUTPUT -p tcp --dport 25 -j MARK --set-mark 0x2
iptables -t mangle -I PREROUTING -i eth2 -p tcp --dport 25 -j MARK --set-mark 0x2

iptables -t nat -I POSTROUTING -s 192.168.1.XXX/24 -o eth0 -j SNAT --to-source 121.XXX.XX.XXX
```

Comment: Thank you very much. You have given me exact solution. I will try this on my vmware setup. vmware setup is identical to my server setup. I have CentOS 5.2 with iptables 1.3.5-5XX. I am getting an error "RTNETLINK answers: Invalid argument" for ip route add 121.XXX.XX.XXX/MASK dev eth0 src 121.XXX.XX.XXX table sendmail. I am searching a reason for this error. Thanks

Comment: MASK needs to be your actual mask, and 121.xxx.xx.xxx your actual network.

Use ip ro sh to see what it is in the main table.

Comment: I am trying this on my virtual server (CentOS5.2). I have two lan cards on this virtual server. I do get internet access from two different sources. One from 192.168.1.66 and other from 192.168.129.1
So my mask would be 192.168.1.0/24. I am not using public IP for this virtual server. Please let me know if you need to know any other information. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

I did something similar using shorewall.
Everything is based on marking and filtering packets and applying on them some rules.
Everything should be explained in the larc howt:  http://lartc.org/howto/index.html
The process should be like this (i have to re-read something, i did it few months ago):

- the packet come from internal net
- netfilter apply on the traffic some MARK
- rules based on marks route the packet trough the right device

Comment: Really thanks for your inputs. I am getting error for "ip route add $P1_NET dev $IF1 src $IP1" from http://lartc.org/howto/lartc.rpdb.multiple-links.html. I am giving actual command like this " ip route add 192.168.1.0/24 dev eth0 src 192.168.1.66 table tata" I have added entry for tata in rt_table. Do you have any idea about this error. I have become mad on this error.

Comment: Which error do you get exactly?

Comment: I am getting "RTNETLINK answers: Invalid argument".